# Covariance of random variable as a function of distribution of noise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random

Consider the following stochastic difference equation

\begin{equation}
x(t+1) = x(t) + \nu(t+1)
\end{equation}
where, $x(t)\in\mathrm{R}$ be one dimensional and $\nu(t)$ be the disturbance with an unknown probability distribution. The first $2$ moments of the disturbance is known to us as a function of time and it is also known that its third central moment is non-zero, although its value is not known. Given the distribution of $x(0)$, my task is to estimate the distribution of $x(t)$ over time such that it is correct up to second order.

Here is what I did:

Let us call the mean and covariance of $\nu(t)$ as $m(t)$ and $Q(t)$. At time $t = 0$, I approximated the distribution $\nu(t)$ with a Gaussian distribution having mean and covariance as $m(0)$ and $Q(0)$. Since the difference is linear, the distribution of $x(t); t>0$ will be Gaussian and unscented transformation can be used to find the first two moments of $x(t)$.

In other words, irrespective of the actual distribution of the disturbance, if its first $n\ge2$ moments are known, we can obtain the correct covariance of $x(t)$ by assuming $\nu(t)$ to be normally distributed.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: "Is this approach correct?" Well, as stated, "assuming $\nu(t)$  to be normally distributed" looks pretty arbitrary.

Comment: $\nu(t) $ is white noise?

Comment: Yes. $\nu(t)$ is white noise.

Answer (score 1):

Letting  $\mu(t) = E[X(t)]$ we have
$\mu(t) = \mu(t-1) + m(t) $

Hence  $\mu(t) = m(t)+m(t-1)+m(t-2)+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty m(t-k)$

Letting  $r(t,s)=E[ X(t)X(t-s)]$ , $r(t,0)=\sigma_x^2(t)+\mu(t)^2$ multiplying $x(t) = x(t-1) + \nu(t)$ by itself and assuming $\nu(t)$ is white noise (its samples are uncorrelated), we get

$$r(t,0) =r(t-1,0) + Q(t)+m(t)^2+2 \,m(t-1)\mu(t)$$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Thanks. I can go from here. But I think there are some minor typos in your calculations:
$\mu(t) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}m(t-k) + \mu(0)$. and

$r(t,0) = r(t-1,0) + Q(t) + m(t)^2 + 2\mu(t-1)m(t)$.
Additionally, the equation for $r(t,0)$ is same as the one obtained using the prediction step of Kalman Filter. Since the equations of Kalman filters are exactly correct for a linear Gaussian system and upto second order for any linear non-Gaussian system, I was wondering whether assumption of $\nu(t)$ to have Gaussian distribution will anyway change the equation of $r(t,0)$.